# Index 'text' MongoDB - 'text' is not supported

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database, nosql

I'm having troubles when creating a text Index on my collection with Mongo. In my case, the property I'm trying to map to, is called url, and it's a text.

Here's what I'm getting:

[image: db.Property.createIndex({url: "text"})]

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Comment: You can have no more than 1 text index per collection, and in case you are using a relict version < 2.4, even less than that.

Answer (score 5):

After some search, I found out that MongoDB provided on Azure (DOCUMENTDB...) does not support it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-indexing-policies